# C# WPF DataGrid ScrollIntoView not working with touch

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, touch

I try to scroll to the last selected item in a WPF `DataGrid` on the `Loaded` event. The `DataGrid` sits in a `Tab`. Everything is working when I test it in a normal Windows environment. But as soon as I *touch* the TabPage on a tablet instead of *clicking* it, it doesn't scroll to my last selected item.
This is my code so far:

```
private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentItem = dataGrid.SelectedItem;

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = sh.GetDataTable(<SQL Select statement>).DefaultView;

    if (!(currentItem == null))
    {
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(currentItem);
    }
}
```

I've also tried the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103823) but it didn't work.

**Edit:**

For testing purposes I completely removed the `dataGrid_Loaded` event. Now I'm only loading data into the `DataGrid` at the start of the program. Even now it keeps the scroll position when I switch between tabs with mouse *clicks* but not with *touch*! Is this a bug in the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of the MSDN Community I was able to solve the problem.

I had to scroll to the end of the `DataGrid`, do a `UpdateLayout()` and then scroll to the `Item` I want.
Additionally I can't just set the `ItemsSource` every time because then the `Item` I saved before is not a valid `Item` of the `DataGrid` anymore.

So finally my `dataGrid_Loaded` method looks like this:

```
private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object currentPos = dataGrid.SelectedItem;

    if (dataGrid.ItemsSource == null)
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = sh.GetDataTable("<SQL query>").DefaultView;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }

    if (currentPos != null)
    {
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);
        dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(currentPos);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone else who has the same problem.

For reference [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/9395c0ae-aa11-4a88-b9eb-2bea310fd4e7/c-wpf-datagrid-scrollposition-auf-tabitem-mit-touch) is my german MSDN thread in which my problem was solved.